# Show/hide inputs based on numericInput and actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

The shiny app has the following elements:

- one `numericInput` field with values between 0 and 3
- one `uiOutput` which contains three hidden `textInput` fields
- one `actionButton`

What I would like to achieve is to `show` the hidden `textInput` fields after a button click. The number of fields shown depends on the number selected in the `numericInput` The **fully functional code below** succeeds in doing that; however, there is an issue I can't seem to find a solution to. For example, if I select `3` and click the button, the 3 hidden `textInput` fields appear (yay!), but then if I immediately select a number lower than `3` and click the button, the unwanted fields still remain. How can I achieve that? Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "How many inputs do you want to show?", value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),

  uiOutput(outputId = "out"),

  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Click me!")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$out <- renderUI({
    numinputs <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
      textInput(inputId = paste0("txt", i), label = paste0("Text input ", i))
    })
    shinyjs::hidden(numinputs)
  })

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$go, handlerExpr = {
    for(i in seq(input$num)){
      shinyjs::show(id = paste0("txt", i))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is similar to @SBista 's but without the `nout` variable.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),
    
    numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "How many inputs do you want to show?", value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),
    
    uiOutput(outputId = "out"),
    
    actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Click me!")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$out <- renderUI({
        numinputs <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
            textInput(inputId = paste0("txt", i), label = paste0("Text input ", i))
        })
        shinyjs::hidden(numinputs)
    })
    
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$go, handlerExpr = {
        n <- seq(length.out = as.numeric(input$num))
        lapply(seq(3), function(i) {
            if(i %in% n) {
                shinyjs::show(id = paste0("txt", i))
            } else{
                shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("txt", i))
            }
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## #edit - without shinyjs/dinamically creating

```
# if you comment the lines marked with # no-button
# the app will change the number of textInputs as soon as you change the numericInput
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "How many inputs do you want to show?", value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),
    uiOutput(outputId = "out"),
    actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Click me!") # no-button
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$out <- renderUI({
        input$go # no-button
        isolate( # no-button
            numinputs <- lapply(seq(length.out = req(input$num)), function(i){
                textInput(inputId = paste0("txt", i), label = paste0("Text input ", i))
            })
        ) # no-button
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I didn't really explain much in my answer.  Did you understand what we did there? `hidden()` only initializes the `textInput()` as an invisible object. `show()` and `hide()` are the ones that react to the user.

Comment: I understood quite well. What I was not able to figure out (before your answer) was the way you set up the `n` variable and the `lapply` loop. Very cleverly done!

Comment: I just realized that you might not need to use `shinyjs`. You could dinamically create the `textInput`s as needed. I'll edit my answer and add this other option.

Comment: With `conditionPanel()`?

Comment: Since you are already creating the `textInput`s on the server side, you can create them as needed instead of creating them all at once and then hidding them.

Comment: That's true. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just saw the edit. Thank you very much once again. I did not know of the `req` function. I will study the code to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code to do exactly what you wanted.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "How many inputs do you want to show?", value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),

  uiOutput(outputId = "out"),

  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Click me!")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  nout <- 0

  output$out <- renderUI({
    numinputs <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
      textInput(inputId = paste0("txt", i), label = paste0("Text input ", i))
    })
    shinyjs::hidden(numinputs)
  })

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$go, handlerExpr = {


      if(nout > input$num){ # If the current no. of inputs is less than previous hide the inputs
        for(i in nout:(nout-as.numeric(input$num))){
          shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("txt", i)) 
        } 

      }else{
        for(i in seq(input$num)){
        shinyjs::show(id = paste0("txt", i)) 
      }

    }

    nout <<- input$num
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It helps a ton. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Could you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you?